# Image open in Windows Photo Viwer with python3

Tags: image, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.2 and I am trying to open a jpg in Windows Photo Viewer(the default set program in windows) but instead, it is opening in photoshop. This is the code I have:

```
from PIL import Image

image=Image.open('Tulips.jpg')
image.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: check what your default program is to view those file types

Comment: My default program is Windows Photo Viwer

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your default application for opening jpg's is Windows Photo Viewer if you want to have them open in that. It seems that your current application for viewing jpg's is in fact photoshop.

To change the default application, right-click in windows explorer and select "open with > choose another app" or "choose default app" or whatever it is (depends on windows version) and choose Windows Photo Viewer **and ensure you click always use this app**.